# Continue my Web browsing in another machine

Tags: wireless-networking

Sometimes I am browsing the Web and I run into some page that is really long, and I think it will be a lot better if I keep reading it in bed with my tablet... Sometimes it can be a bunch of pages opened in multiple tabs.

Whenever that happens, I usually pick up the tablet and google the page I was reading on the computer, so I can read it on the tablet. But that is kind of dumb, and very inconvenient when it's a bunch of pages. There has to be a better way.

The computer runs Linux. The tablet is a BlackBerry Playbook. A BlackBerry means that there is pretty much no software to help me with anything at all, so I need an agnostic solution.

The computer and the tablet are on the same Wifi network so they can sort of communicate. At least I can run a Web server on the computer and access it on the tablet. I can make smart pages with cgi scripting if necessary. Other ideas can be very difficult because the Playbook is so very limited.

I thought that I can just copy paste links into a text file, and a cgi page will parse it and turn the pure text links into proper HTML links, then I just have to bookmark that page on the tablet. That's an idea. What other ideas would you propose?

Comment: How about using a read-it-later web service like [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/)? Pocket is free. And you can save webpages and access them on the Pocket website or app.

Comment: I am familiar with Pocket. I didn't really like it, it's not so convenient as it sounds and I don't think it's available on the Playbook. Some Android apps will work on the Playbook, but I never tried Pocket because I tried it on my Android phone and I didn't like it. Is it even compatible with a Linux desktop anyway? (will check later)

Comment: On Linux, [use Pocket Bookmarklet for browser](http://help.getpocket.com/customer/portal/articles/483627-using-the-pocket-bookmarklet). On Playbook, use browser to log on to Pocket website for getting saved article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestions made here, I tried the Instapaper solution with reasonably good results.

However, I found that my own initial solution works better: I am copying and pasting links into a text file that is bookmarked in my shell. Since I always have a Web server running, I made a very small and simple CGI script that parses the text file and turns the pure text links into proper HTML links. That page is then served by the computer on the local network, bookmarked and accessible from the tablet. Once that page is opened in the tablet, I can click the links and enjoy.

I appreciate all the suggestions, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a print-to-pdf printer to make a pdf of the webpage and you can send it to a network folder. In your tablet you will access that folder and open the file.

Comment: That would work, but is inferior to the idea I proposed myself. Printing to PDF is slow, opening it is also slow, and reading PDFs is awful because the fonts don't scale. I avoid PDFs like the plague because of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Evernote and its browser's add-on. Use the add-on to save web pages to your account, then use your tablet to read these pages using a browser or the native Evernote client for BB. The add-on works in Chrome, don't know about others. The Evernote's BB client is found here: http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/1700/?lang=pt_br, but I'm not sure it can diplay your notes. Anyway you can login to the website to see your notes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of bookmark-syncing add-on in the browser; an option on many of them is to sync open tabs.  Firefox's built-in sync does this (I believe).

Comment: Please mention a specific service that works for OP's hardware.

Comment: Can't you install Android apps on the Playbook?  If so, you can install the mobile version of Firefox.

Comment: I agree that this kind of suggestion has to be more specific. At any rate, although some Android apps will work on the Playbook, Firefox doesn't. I use the apk2bar website to convert Android apps into bar files, and the Firefox apk can't even be converted. Besides, that would force me to use Firefox on the tablet, which is not necessarily good. I really don't like it on my Android phone because it's really large and heavy and crashes often.